# Searching Master List For Matches

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to modify some code I had put together and having a bit of a difficult time converting it. My previous code looked through files in a folder, pulled the name from the file, and used that to determine if it was the right file. I am now trying to run through a master list (one file) where the names are in cells instead of on a file name.

The first userform asks for a `first` and `last` name and presents a button, `search`.

```
Private Sub search_Click() ' In userform1

' Declare and set variables
Dim fname As String, lname As String
Dim Path As String, fCell As Range, fAdd As String
Path = "C:\Master List.xlsx"
fname = userform1.firstname_Search.Text
lname = userform1.lastname_Search.Text
' Store the name searched for
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1") = fname
    .Range("A2") = lname
End With

Workbooks.Open (Path)

' Ensure the name searched for exists in the master list
With Workbooks("Master List").Worksheets("Master List").Range("A:A")
    Set fCell = .Find(fname)
    If Not fCell Is Nothing And fCell = fname Then
        ' Column A is first name, B is middle initial, C is last name, D is suffix, F is date of birth
        If fCell.Offset(0, 2) = lname Then
            userform2.firstname_Text.Text = fCell
            userform2.middlename_Text.Text = fCell.Offset(0, 1)
            userform2.lastname_Text.Text = Trim(fCell.Offset(0, 2) & " " & fCell.Offset(0, 3))
            userform2.dob_Text.Text = fCell.Offset(0, 5)
            Unload Me
            userform2.Show vbModeless
            userform3.Label1.Caption = "Now that we have the information from " & fCell & "'s file, what would you like to do?"
        Else
            MsgBox ("I could not find a client by that name.")
            Workbooks("Master List").Close False
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("I could not find a client by that name.")
        Workbooks("Master List").Close False
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

This section appears to run fine and will pull up the first entry that matches the first name and last name entered. The issue is occurring when the second userform, `userform2` is pulled up, because it displays the relevant information to determine if the right person has been pulled up. It presents `first`, `middle`, `last` names and the `date of birth` along with a `Yes` and `No` button. Clicking `Yes` pulls the information (which I have not written yet), while clicking `No` should cycle through the remaining matches (for example, if there are 3 William Jackson s listed, clicking `No` should cycle to the second; a second `No` should cycle to the third; it should then present the MsgBox because no other entries exist for that name).

The issue is that I cannot find a way to cycle past the first `No`; if `No` was clicked a second time, it wouldn't go past the second entry found. I know this is because of the `Set fCell = .Find(fname)` and `Set fCell = .FindNext(fCell)` at the beginning, but *short of making a cell dedicated to how many times `No` has been clicked*, is there a better way to do this?

```
Private Sub no_Click() ' In userform2

' Declare and set variables
Dim fname As String, lname As String
Dim Path As String, fCell As Range, fAdd As String
Path = "C:\Master List.xlsx"
With Workbooks("FirstWorkbook").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    fname = .Range("A1")
    lname = .Range("A2")
End With

' Ensure a client exists
With Workbooks("Master List").Worksheets("Master List").Range("A:A")
    Set fCell = .Find(fname)
    Set fCell = .FindNext(fCell)
    If Not fCell Is Nothing And fCell = fname Then
        If fCell.Offset(0, 2) = lname Then
            firstname_Text.Text = fCell
            middlename_Text.Text = fCell.Offset(0, 1)
            lastname_Text.Text = Trim(fCell.Offset(0, 2) & " " & fCell.Offset(0, 3))
            dob_Text.Text = fCell.Offset(0, 5)
            userform3.Label1.Caption = "Now that we have the information from " & fCell & "'s file, what would you like to do?"
            With Workbooks("FirstWorkbook").Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Range("A1") = fCell
                .Range("A2") = fCell.Offset(0, 2)
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox ("I could not find a client by that name.")
            Workbooks("Master List").Close False
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("I could not find a client by that name.")
        Workbooks("Master List").Close False
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Maybe there's a better way to use one userform, or a better way to search through the master list; either a solution that helps to solve this problem or a point in the right direction so I can look at a different way to do it would help me greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest factoring out the Find into a standalone function, and have it return all matches to the search value (in the example below it returns a collection object).  You'd then store that return value in a global field in your form.

It's much easier to cycle through the return value of a function like this than to re-run the search (starting at a different location) every time the use clicks No.

```
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: After a bit of digging and a little fiddling around with the code, I found exactly what I wanted. There's still a lot I have to learn regarding Collections and their return value (mostly in terms of display and modification), but for what I need it to do now and quickly, this does just that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to list all files in all folders and all sub-folders. Check out this link.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Download the file; that's the way to go.  Once all paths and all file names are listed in your Excel worksheet, you can do all kinds of comparisons, manipulations, and the like.

```
    Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String)  

    '--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\"  

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject  
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder  
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File  

        Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject  
        Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)  

        '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured  

        r = 14  
        For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files  
            Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13  
            Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name  
            Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path  
            Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size  
            Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type  
            Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified  
            Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"  

            r = r + 1   ' next row number  
        Next FileItem  

        Set FileItem = Nothing  
        Set SourceFolder = Nothing  
        Set FSO = Nothing  
    End Sub  


Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)  

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No  

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject  
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder  
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File  
'Dim r As Long  
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject  
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)  

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured  

    r = 14  
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files  
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13  
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name  
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path  
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size  
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type  
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified  
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"  

        r = r + 1   ' next row number  
    Next FileItem  

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.  

    If Subfolders = True Then  
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders  
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True  
        Next SubFolder  
    End If  

    Set FileItem = Nothing  
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing  
    Set FSO = Nothing  
End Sub
```

[image]